# Как делать динамические роуты в PHP?

Tags: php

Имеется один физический раздел который называется catalog из него читается файл index.php в котором будет расположена основная логика каталога. Как можно сделать так, чтобы из этого раздела создавались страницы к примеру так, mysite/catalog/1/, чтобы элементы выводились динамически из базы данных по его ID, без физического создания файлов в разделе каталога?

Comment: если у вас апач то читайте про [tag:htaccess]

Comment: Или парсить строку и разбивать её, или да, вариант с apache/nginx через конфиги и обычные параметры PHP